# UTF8 Decoding with NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, utf-8

I am new to Objective-C and try to convert a malformed UTF8 encoded NSString to a wellformed one using the example on [apples docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html).

```
NSString *theString = @"LÃ¼gen"; //should be "ü"
NSString *asciiString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Original: %@ (length %d)", theString, [theString length]);  
NSLog(@"Converted: %@ (length %d)", asciiString, [asciiString length]);
```

Result:

```
Original: LÃ¼gen (length 6)
Converted: LA1/4gen (length 8)
```

This here is doing nothing:

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
                 [theString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

This here crashes my app

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
                 [theString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Anyone any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you dump the strings as hex? I don't read malformed UTF8 fluently :)

Comment: this is an "ü" don't know how to get the hex value ;)

Comment: Please post details of the crash in any question that involves a crash.

Comment: @Jano: You should add that as answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"Ã¼";
const char *c = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSString *newString = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:c encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",newString); // ü
```

"Malformed UTF-8 sequence" means a sequence of bytes which are invalid in UTF-8. Your problem is unexpected results after parsing a string with a different encoding than the one used by the original author of the string.

Hexadecimal data `C3 BC` **parsed** with UTF-8 encoding is character `ü`. Instead you used Latin-1 encoding, which results in `Ã¼`. Then you created a NSString from the Latin-1 parsed string, which means you **converted** the Latin-1 string to a UTF-16 string (which is the native format of NSString).

Representing a given data in different encodings shows up as different chars, but doesn't change the data. Converting to a different encoding does change the data in an attempt to reproduce the same characters. Example: The character `Ã¼` is `C3 83 C2 BC` in UTF-8, but `C3 BC` in Latin-1. So I converted to the same chars in Latin-1 to get the original data, and then I parsed as UTF-8.