# How to check NSString encode

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, unicode, nsstring

I read cert info by use

```
NSString *summary = CFBridgingRelease(SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(cert));
```

which get the cert summary, when the summary is chinese, such as `中`，the summary return as `ä¸`

how can i encode `ä¸` to `中` correct?

The code how i get cert summary

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef query = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(nil, 4, nil, nil);
CFDictionaryAddValue(query, kSecClass, kSecClassCertificate);

CFDictionaryAddValue(query, kSecMatchLimit, (const void *)@(100));
CFDictionaryAddValue(query, kSecReturnRef, kCFBooleanTrue);

CFArrayRef items;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, (CFTypeRef *)&items);
NSArray *certificates = CFBridgingRelease(items);
for (int i = 0; i < certificates.count; i++)
{
    SecCertificateRef certificate = (__bridge SecCertificateRef)certificates[i];
    NSString *summary = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certificate);
    NSLog(@"%@", summary);
}
```

when summary is a chinese string, the result is not right.

Comment: How did you examine the summary string? Show the code or debugger commands you used to display/print/log it and the exact output.

Comment: add the code in the question, thx.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on the `SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary()` line, which makes me wonder how this differs from your real code. Anyway, it may be that this is just a bug in `SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary()`. An `NSString` or `CFString` is intended to be encoding-neutral. Or, another way to think about it, it should be already decoded into an internal representation. The API is in terms of "characters", by which it actually means UTF-16 code units, but the internal representation could be anything. It should not be possible to get an encoding mistake like this.

Comment: I suppose it's also possible the certificate itself is malformed. For example, it may be that it should use some specific encoding like UTF-8 for its summary, but the data in the certificate is actually using some other encoding. Does it look correct in the Keychain Access utility?

Comment: thx for help. finally solve the problem by decode utf8. i post an answer for help others

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem.
First i print every char in the nsstring, looks like

`228 184 173`

And chinese character use 3 char in utf8, so i switch it to bin

```
0b1110 0100
0b10 111000
0b10 101101
//for utf8 to unicode, it's
0100111000101101
//to int
20013
//which is 中 at unicode
```

And for [UTF8 Decoding with NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850026/utf8-decoding-with-nsstring) help, finally switch the string form utf8 to unicode.